Manual grinder factors for dark roast
I already have the J Ultra hand grinder. I tend to consume medium or dark roasts with dark chocolate undertones. For this coffee roast & flavour profile, what should I keep in mind when buying a (new) hand grinder?
For eg., the J Ultra being an espresso grinder tends to provide fines when grinding for pour over. One person said that fines will reduce "clarity" in the cup ... yet, for dark chocolate undertones you need fines.
Is that actually true? Are there other factors to be aware of?

That's my understanding as well, without having personally performed the hard science: fines tend to muddy the flavours of coffee, while enhancing chocolatey, roasty notes, and the J series makes more fines than the rest of the 1Zpresso lineup. I suspect that's a stellar grinder for your taste preferences.
